# Typescript (tsc) not picking up my .ts file

Tags: typescript

> tsc --version Version 2.8.3

In my firebase project, at root I have `tsconfig.json` as below;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./",
    "types": ["mocha"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "project": "/**/*.ts",
    "watch": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings/browser.d.ts", "typings/browser"]
}
```

And under following folder I have `test.ts` file like below;

```
app-firebase\functions\Repositories\test.ts
```

Code:

```
abstract class AnimalAbstract {     
  abstract makeSound(): void;
  move(): void {
    console.log("roaming the earth...");
  }
}
```

If I run `tsc` at root folder, it does not compile file into `.js`. But if I navigate to folder and run `tsc test.ts` it compiles.

I also tried to remove `project` parameter in `config` file, but did not work as well.

How can I make it `watch` entire project folder?

Comment: try with `tsc  -p` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had to add `rootDir` in config.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./",
    "types": ["mocha"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "watch": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings/browser.d.ts", "typings/browser"]
}
```